# Basic Java Menu with Switch Case

Tags: java

The code will compile, but there seems to be an error with my menu. The user will select one of the choices and the program should execute, but When choosing a selection nothing happens. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Tutorial{
public static void main(String args[]){
Geek myGeek = new Geek("Geek");
System.out.println("Command Options: ");
System.out.println("a: Geek's Name");
System.out.println("b: Num Questions Asked");
System.out.println("c: All Numbers Are the Same");
System.out.println("d: Sum Between Two Integers");
System.out.println("e: Repeat the String");
System.out.println("f: It is Palindrome");
System.out.println("?: Display");
System.out.println("q: Quit");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String choice = scan.nextLine();
do {
switch (choice){
    case "a":
        myGeek.getName();
        break;
    case "b":
        myGeek.getnumberofQuestions();
        break;
    case "c":

        System.out.println("Enter the first number");
        int input1 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the second number");
        int input2 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the third number");
        int input3 = scan.nextInt();
        myGeek.allTheSame(input1, input2, input3);
        break;
    case "d":
        System.out.println("Enter the first number");
        int num1 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the second number");
        int num2 = scan.nextInt();
        myGeek.sum(num1, num2);
        break;
    case "e":
        System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
        String word1 = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");
        int numberOfTimes = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the third number");
        myGeek.repeat(word1, numberOfTimes);
        break;
    case "f":
        System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
        String word2 = scan.nextLine();
        myGeek.isPalindrome(word2);
        break;
    case "?":
            System.out.println("Command Options: ");
            System.out.println("a: Geek's Name");
            System.out.println("b: Num Questions Asked");
            System.out.println("c: All Numbers Are the Same");
            System.out.println("d: Sum Between Two Integers");
            System.out.println("e: Repeat the String");
            System.out.println("f: It is Palindrome");
            System.out.println("?: Display");
            System.out.println("q: Quit");
            break;
        }  }while (choice != "q");

}
}
```

Here is the what it looks like when run:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Avf8x.png

Comment: Compare string values with `equals`, not with `!=` or `==`.

Comment: This is my first time using a switch case. Would it be case.equals?

Comment: Just checking but are you using JDK7?

Comment: @user2943817 I was referring to your `while` condition.  The switch cases look good, assuming you're using JDK7+, which allows `String`s in cases.

Comment: Im currently using JRE7.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you definitely need to move code which gets input inside the loop :

```
        String choice = null;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            choice = scan.nextLine();
            switch (choice) {
            case "a":
        .........
            } // end of switch
        } while (!choice.equals("q")); // end of loop
```

Otherwise, you input once and switch on that input indefinitely (unless it is "q")

**Edit :** 
You also need to change terminating condition to `while (!choice.equals("q"));` 
for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

This also depends on which version of the JDK they're using.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

http://java.dzone.com/articles/new-java-7-feature-string

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

You read input only once - outside of do..while - probably not what you want (otherwise you'd be stuck in infinite loop).
most likely the intent was this: `while ((choice = scan.nextLine()) != "q");`
As far as why you don't see anything when running, it depends on what `myGeek.getName()` does.
As name suggests its a simple getter, if this is a case then it returns the name but it does not print anything on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

One issue you have, as mentioned by @rgettman, is that comparing `String`s in Java using `==` or `!=` will compare the Object reference of the `String` not the value; basically are the two `String`s the same Object?  In this case (and most cases) you want to compare the value.

Change `while (choice != "q");` to `while (!choice.equals("q"));` to compare the values.

A slightly different explanation:

Right now you are entering a character, say "a", matching your `case` for "a" and breaking from the switch/case.  However when your program gets  to the `while` it basically checks whether `choice` *is* `"q"` so your program goes back into the `do/while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

i think you want something like this:

```
....           
        System.out.println("d: Sum Between Two Integers");
        System.out.println("e: Repeat the String");
        System.out.println("f: It is Palindrome");
        System.out.println("?: Display");
        System.out.println("q: Quit");

        String choice;
        do {
            System.out.println("Select something: ");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            choice = scan.nextLine();

            switch (choice){
                case "a":
                    myGeek.getName();
                    break;
                case "b":
                    myGeek.getnumberofQuestions();
                    break;
                case "c":

                    System.out.println("Enter the first number");
                    int input1 = scan.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter the second number");
....
```

if not --->>>> for what you need do -> while??

and check, if your java is 7 or heighter, and check your getMethods() -> if thay return anything

Answer (score -1):

Your loop (do {} while(condition)) will loop infinite when you enter some string different "q" because condition always is true.
try with :

```
while (!choice.equals("q")) {
    switch (choice) {
        case "a":
        myGeek.getName();
        break;
  case "b":
        myGeek.getnumberofQuestions();
        break;
   case "c":

        System.out.println("Enter the first number");
        int input1 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the second number");
        int input2 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the third number");
        int input3 = scan.nextInt();
        myGeek.allTheSame(input1, input2, input3);
        break;
    case "d":
        System.out.println("Enter the first number");
        int num1 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the second number");
        int num2 = scan.nextInt();
        myGeek.sum(num1, num2);
        break;
    case "e":
        System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
        String word1 = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");
        int numberOfTimes = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the third number");
        myGeek.repeat(word1, numberOfTimes);
        break;
    case "f":
        System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
        String word2 = scan.nextLine();
        myGeek.isPalindrome(word2);
        break;
    case "?":
        System.out.println("Command Options: ");
        System.out.println("a: Geek's Name");
        System.out.println("b: Num Questions Asked");
        System.out.println("c: All Numbers Are the Same");
        System.out.println("d: Sum Between Two Integers");
        System.out.println("e: Repeat the String");
        System.out.println("f: It is Palindrome");
        System.out.println("?: Display");
        System.out.println("q: Quit");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you do? Please don't just post your improved version, write what you have done and why.